# How to run groovy script in java?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy script and i want to execute it in java. Could someone provide me with further documentation / examples on how this is possible?

Comment: This question is very much on topic with groovy-java integration.  Answer below is a starting point.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Basic Java+Groovy Integration:

```
// call groovy expressions from Java code
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("foo", new Integer(2));
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

Object value = shell.evaluate(groovyScript);
```

[**See this article for more ways to call Groovy from Java**](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html)

**PS:** You need to include `groovy-all-m.n.m.jar` e.g. `groovy-all-2.1.6.jar` in your Java program, [for example](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks anubhava. Solved my purpose. I have been able to call groovy script from java source file. :)