# How to execute a groovy script within another groovy in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a groovy script say `test.groovy`.  It has all the instruction to be executed and is stored at a location.

I am creating a SOAP test where I have a groovy step and I want to write in it the  code to execute the above script `test.groovy`.

How can I do this?

Comment: May be you want to provide some more context and what are you trying to achieve? By the way, what does `test.groovy` does?

Comment: Groovy is just Java. Your "script" needs to be in a class and a method, and you would call it just like any other method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run groovy script in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790198/how-to-run-groovy-script-in-java)

Comment: My test.groovy is used to make jdbc connection to my oracle database and perform some sql query.I have externalize this test.groovy as it will be used repeatativly and I want to execute it during my soap test.in my soaptest case I have added a groovy test step where I want to call this script

Comment: You want to try the script from above mentioned link, that should work. You again need to repeatedly the test.groovy from a groovy. And how do you get the result to calling script to evaluate or to make assertions?

Comment: I dont need to assertion check for this.this test groovy is doing some kind of data insertion in sql and inserting the customer properties in SOAPUI.

Comment: @SiKing, Just because it is Java its not feasible to call another class since its not a Java IDE, but SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following three lines into the SoapUI Groovy Script.

```
def project= testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.workspace.getProjectByName("projectName")
def runner = project.testSuites['testSuiteName'].testCases['testCaseName'].testSteps["groovyScriptName"].run(testRunner, context)
log.info ("runner status ....... : " + runner.getStatus()) // prints the response of the nested script in the log
```

Change the *projectName, testSuiteName, testCaseName, groovyScriptName* according to your SoapUI Project. (*groovyScriptName* is the script which needs to be called)

It just worked on me, and ran a Groovy Script from another groovy script.

Ps: Just in case to verify if the project is being called properly,
 add the following code line in between the def project and def runner.

```
log.info project.name // just to verify the project
```

Comment: How to call a specific method in another script and save it return value