# To write a groovy script that should be available in db, so that I can add/edit evaluation rules dynamically

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

I have certain set of rules to be executed which is now part of a spring-boot application. I need to keep all my rules in to a groovy script and this groovy script should be available in database, so that I can add/edit the rules dynamically. I thought through various approaches, but lost. It would be great help if you can give me the approach.

Comment: please clarify what you mean by rules, are this groovy-code fragments you want to execute/evaluate at runtime? Also clarify what you mean by "should be available in database"

Comment: rules in sense set of conditions(like a particular status should be yes and some other if conditions) which are written in java and are specific to my spring-boot application. The groovy script should be inserted in the database and whenever we want we should be able to make changes dynamically like adding new conditions or removing conditions.

Comment: still not clear enough: you know how to execute the code snippets? E.g. in my project we store the code as strings containing MVEL code and then execute them as "MVEL.executeExpression(...)" but the same can be done with groovy snippets. I assume you know how to store a simple string in a database and later read it to execute it. If you don't know how to execute groovy snippets from java look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790198/how-to-run-groovy-script-in-java