# How to run groovy in Java

Tags: java, groovy

Hi everyone tried different ways to run a groovy in java with no luck, had read some documentation but things aren't that clear at the moment.

Anyone may know how to run this groovy?

```
package com.test.dev.search;

public class SearchQueryBase implements SearchQuery {    

    public QueryString getMatterQuery( SearchFilter filter ) {
        String[] terms = filter.getSearchTerm().toLowerCase().split( " " );
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

This is a .groovy file (the one from above), I've tried the follow to run it without luck.

Down here is the Java class in which I want to run the above Groovy and execute `getMatterQuery()` to see the output from java main.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws CGException {

    String TEMPLATE_PACKAGE_PREFIX = "<path_to_groovy_file.";

    String templateFileName = TEMPLATE_PACKAGE_PREFIX + "SearchQueryBase";

    SearchFilter test = null;

    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setVariable("filter", test);

    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

    shell.evaluate(templateFileName);

    System.out.println("Finish");
}
```

EDIT #1

This is the error I'm getting when I run it;

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Common for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `SearchQueryBase` file is a Groovy file? It's legal Groovy, but it looks exactly like Java. In either case, the normal way to "run" it would be to compile it to a class file and use it normally (i.e., `new SearchQueryBase()`).

Comment: Yes I'm saying SearchQueryBase is a Groovy file. Doing a new SearchQueryBase() was the first thing I tried, however I can't import it. My thoughts are because it's not a Java file to be imported.

Comment: I guess the groovy file should contain a script instead of a class when using groovy shell.

Comment: If you are using a java class, you can as well bundle treat it as java. Anyway if you want to use groovy to load java then you can use [Groovy classloader](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html#groovyclassloader)

Comment: @gagansingh I think it would be a Java to load groovy, I tried `GroovyShell` but luck in execution

Comment: what exact exception do you have?

Comment: you try to load `SearchQueryBase` file without extension... are you sure file name is not `SearchQueryBase.groovy`?   it's not clear from your code what you are trying to do. are you trying to call getMatterQuery() method in a groovy class?

Comment: @daggett, without .groovy works, Yes, I want to call `getMatterQuery()` from that groovy class in Java main class to see the output.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but please have a look at [How to run groovy script in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17790364/3832970).

Comment: You still have to compile the Groovy class to a `.class` file, such as with `groovyc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

the `GroovyShell.evaluate(java.lang.String scriptText)` accepts string as a groovy text (content), and you try to call it with filename instead. use `shell.evaluate( new File(templateFileName) )`

2.

you can continue using `shell.evaluate( new File(...) )` but keep in your groovy file only content of the method `getMatterQuery()`:

```
String[] terms = filter.getSearchTerm().toLowerCase().split( " " );
...
...
...
```

so you'll have groovy script, and your code should work

3.

if you want to keep groovy as a class and call the method `getMatterQuery()` from this class with parameter, then your java code should be like this:

```
import groovy.lang.*;
...

public static void main(String[]s)throws Exception{
    GroovyClassLoader cl=new GroovyClassLoader();
    //path to base folder where groovy classes located
    cl.addClasspath(path_to_groovy_root); 
    //the groovy file with SearchQueryBase.groovy
    //must be located in "com/test/dev/search" subfolder under path_to_groovy_root
    Class c = cl.loadClass("com.test.dev.search.SearchQueryBase");
    SearchQuery o = (SearchQuery) c.newInstance();
    System.out.println( o.getMatterQuery(test) );
}
```

Comment: 1 and 2 worked perfectly had to make some minor changes but worked. However with 3 I wasn't able to make it work and it would be really great if 3 worked.