# Regex to escape special characters in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to use a regex to scape special characters, right now used it on Java and works perfect, it does exactly what I want `Scape any special character` however I tried this in Groovy but the same line doesn't work, as far I investaged it's because `$` is reserved in Groovy, so far I tried this;

Java: (Does the job)

```
String specialCharRegex = "[\\W|_]";
...
term = term.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, "\\\\$0");
...
```

Groovy:

error

```
String specialCharRegex = "[\\W|_]";
...
term = term.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, "\\\\$0");
...
```

error

```
String specialCharRegex = "[\\W|_]";
...
term = term.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, "\\\\\$0");
...
```

error

```
String specialCharRegex = "[\\W|_]";
...
term = term.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, '\\\\$0');
...
```

error

```
String specialCharRegex = "[\\W|_]";
...
term = term.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, '\\\\$1');
...
```

I use `https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/` to test it.

Output in Groovy should be:

```
Input: test 1& test
Output: test 1\& test

Input: test 1& test 2$
Output: test 1\& test 2\$

Input: test 1& test 2$ test 3%
Output: test 1\& test 2\$ test 3\%

Input: !"@#$%&/()=?
Output: \!\"\@\#\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `[\W|_]` = `[\W_]`, since `|` is a non-word char. Also, it is advised to define regex with slashy strings since the backslashes inside them denote literal backslashes, the ones that are used to form *regex escapes*.

It seems you do not want to match spaces, so you need to subtract `\s` from `[\W_]`, use `/[\W_&&[^\s]]/` regex.

Second, in the replacement part, you may use a single-quoted string literal to avoid interpolating `$0`:

```
.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, '\\\\$0')
```

Else, escape the `$` in the double quoted string literal:

```
.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, "\\\\\$0")
```

A slashy string also works as expected:

```
.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, /\\$0/)
```

See the [online Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/mf8ygk):

```
String specialCharRegex = /[\W_&&[^\s]]/;                                 
println('test 1& test'.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, '\\\\$0'));           // test 1\& test
println('test 1& test 2$'.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, "\\\\\$0"));       // test 1\& test 2\$
println('test 1& test 2$ test 3%'.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, /\\$0/));  // test 1\& test 2\$ test 3\%
println('!"@#$%&/()=?'.replaceAll(specialCharRegex, /\\$0/));             // \!\"\@\#\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?
```

Comment: On ideon.com worked perfect even the ones with errors I posted, it may be the other page I was trying. Could you take a look and help if possible from this one; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159593/how-to-run-groovy-in-java trying to run in a Java (main) a method from a Groovy class.

Comment: It seems strange to use anything other than "quotes" to delimit a string, but I guess that is part of Groovy magic DSL. (Haven't seen `/regex/` slashes since my Perl olden-days.)

Comment: @MarkHu You may learn more about [*slashy strings* here](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string). There are even fancier [*dollar slashy strings*](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_dollar_slashy_string) in which you do not have to escape a `/` and `$`. :)