# Processing the result of a Groovy script in Java

Tags: java, groovy

I followed the answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790198/how-to-run-groovy-script-in-java) to write my own script. However, I do not understand how to convert from `GStringImpl` to `String[]`. How do I do that?

Thanks

```
public class TestGroovy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        binding.setVariable("b", "a|b|c");
        GStringImpl value = (GStringImpl) shell.evaluate("return \"${b.split('|')}\";");// return "b.split('|')";}
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

This prints

```
[a, |, b, |, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my code as follows. I use properties instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
    binding.setProperty("b", "a|b|c");
    shell.evaluate("result = b.tokenize('|');");// return "b.split('|')";}
    List<String> property = (List<String>) shell.getProperty("result");
    System.out.println(property);
    for (String s : property) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```